# Using Nuget Package Manager Dialog in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I have set up a new package source in the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2013. The package source is our Teamcity Nuget Server. When I try to retrieve our Nuget packages from Teamcity from the Package Manager Dialog nothing is retrieved, but when I use the Package Manager Console all our packages is listed. When I use the Console I can see in Fiddler that the package source url is called, but when I use the Package Manager Dialog the package source url is not called.

I have tried to uninstall and install the Nuget package Manager extension, but that didn't work.
We use the Teamcity Nuget Server public feed url for retrieveing package information.
I'm running VS 2013 as Administrator.

Have any of you experienced the same and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problemm solved itself by restarting Teamcity!